Bug in Flatten crashes kernel
This makes kernel crash on version 13.0.1.
Several other combinations of nested empty braces do the same. Is it present in newer versions?
Flatten[{{{}}}, {3}]

By the way, if am I not mistaken the output should be {{{}}}.
Anything with n=3, 4, 5...
Flatten[Nest[List, Nothing, n], {n}]

Or for example this works
Flatten[{{}, {{{}}}, {{{{}}}}}, {4}]


{{{{}}, {{}}, {{{}}}}}

but this cause crash although the previous list contained all sub-items of this list:
Flatten[{{}, {{{}}}, {{{}}}}, {4}]


Crashes on 14.1

Crashes on "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)".

Apparently goes back many versions. Feel free to add a few other representative examples; I will test them against a proposed fix.

Any insight/speculation why the kernel crashes in this case?

@DanielLichtblau I added some more examples.

It crashes due to a bug insofar as it reached an unexpected case.

I have some feedback in-house suggesting {} might be the appropriate result, the idea being (as best I understand) that implicit levels are empty. I'd like to see what are the arguments against this before proceeding further.

@DanielLichtblau I do not agree. Try Flatten[{{{x}}}, {3}] % /. x -> Nothing You get {{{x}}} {{{}}} ... of course if the former output is correct too

One can argue that substitution with Nothing changes the structure by emptying a level. Hence doing so after flattening need not agree with the result of doing so before flattening. That noted, I will bring your remark to the attention of those weighing in here. (As you might realize, I'm sort of in the middle on this.)

@DanielLichtblau I think replacing by Nothing does not change the number of levels. Both {{{}}} and {{{x}}} have the same number of levels so the flatting should be consistent in both cases. But in the end it is their responsibility so they have to decide.

@DanielLichtblau By the way another option is to throw an error like for example with Flatten[{{{x}}}, {4}] but an error with a different explanation like for example "this code is forbidden" ;-)

In reverse order: (i) I am considering the error message approach, either returning the first argument or returning the full input unevaluated. (ii) That replacement does not remove a level but does (as we both have noted) empty it. I am not certain this matters for Flatten but I defer to what others here will say before trying to finalize a fix.

@DanielLichtblau Since Flatten[{{}}, {2}] outputs {} without an error then Flatten[{{{}}}, {3}] should output also {}. So I changed my mind.

I believe we are on the same page at this point. Thanks for the extra examples.

Crashes on v14.0
